# ERROR installing boto3 using pip on RHEL7 - Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, proxy, pip, boto3

I am attempting to install boto3 on an ec2 instance running RHEL7.6. I am behind a proxy, and the proxy information is listed in /etc/environment. I am certain the proxy is working. I am able to curl the https://pypi.org and use our proxy regularly. I am running Python 2.7.5 and Pip 8.1.2.

I run the following command to produce the 502 Bad Gateway: 
`pip install --proxy http://<redacted-ip>:<redacted-port> -v --log pipinstall1.log boto3`

I've included the --proxy flag because I encountered the same errors without it. I wanted to be sure that the proxy is used by pip, but to no avail.

I apologize for pasting the log directly, but I am unable to use hosting service to attach the log file.

```
  Collecting boto3
  1 location(s) to search for versions of boto3:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/boto3/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/boto3/
  Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/simple/boto3/" in the cache
  Returning cached "301 Moved Permanently" response (ignoring date and etag information)
  Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/boto3/" in the cache
  No cache entry available
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/boto3/'): Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway',))': /simple/boto3/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (2): pypi.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/boto3/'): Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway',))': /simple/boto3/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (3): pypi.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/boto3/'): Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway',))': /simple/boto3/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (4): pypi.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/boto3/'): Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway',))': /simple/boto3/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (5): pypi.org
  Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/boto3/'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway',))': /simple/boto3/
  Starting new HTTPS connection (6): pypi.org
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/boto3/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/boto3/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway',))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement boto3 (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for boto3
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 307, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 370, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 522, in _prepare_file
    finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 268, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 491, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for boto3
Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/json" in the cache
Returning cached "301 Moved Permanently" response (ignoring date and etag information)
Looking up "https://pypi.org/pypi/pip/json" in the cache
No cache entry available
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org
There was an error checking the latest version of pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/outdated.py", line 126, in pip_version_check
    headers={"Accept": "application/json"},
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 487, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 378, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 606, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 179, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 465, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi/pip/json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway',)))
```

**Update**

To eliminate the potential that Python 2.7.5 is too old to download from PyPi, I stood up a new ec2 instance running RHEL 8. This instance is running Python 3.6.8 and pip 9.0.3. I verified the proxy is working via `curl https://pypi.org/simple/boto3/` and it returned successfully.

I am still receiving the 502 Bad Gateway when running: 
`pip3 --log  pip3_log.txt --proxy http://<redacted-ip>:<redacted-port> --trusted-host pypi.org install boto3`

The output of pip3_log.txt is below:

```
Collecting boto3
  1 location(s) to search for versions of boto3:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/boto3/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/boto3/
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway',))': /simple/boto3/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway',))': /simple/boto3/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway',))': /simple/boto3/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway',))': /simple/boto3/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway',))': /simple/boto3/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/boto3/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/boto3/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway',))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement boto3 (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for boto3
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 346, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 381, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 557, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 514, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for boto3
There was an error checking the latest version of pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 595, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 816, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py", line 294, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 919, in _tunnel
    message.strip()))
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi/pip/json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway',)))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/outdated.py", line 141, in pip_version_check
    headers={"Accept": "application/json"},
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 640, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 640, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 218, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 502, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi/pip/json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 502 Bad Gateway',)))
```

Comment: No need to apologize, pasting the log in the question was the right thing to do. Python 2.7.5 is probably too old to be able to download anything from PyPI as it's compiled against an old version of OpenSSL that doesn't support TLSv1.2; check that with e.g. `python2.7 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION); print(getattr(ssl, 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2', 'No TLSv1.2 support'))"`. You need to upgrade Python 2 to at least Python 2.7.9 to install from PyPI.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I've attempted to install boto3 from a new instance running RHEL8 using an updated version of python and pip. I am incurring the same result as showing in the update section above.

Comment: Did you figure out this issue with RHEL8 , i am stuck and not able to install any package through pip install wget works fine. pip install gives certifciation errors

Comment: Today I have set up tinyproxy on ubuntu18 to test it with RHEL 8 and same version of python and pip3 as you mentioned and it worked. I can say, it could issue with proxy settings. can you show me the output of `curl -v -I google.com` ?  you can hide the proxy server IP in output.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue a few days ago, because I was also using a proxy which had only 2 domains whitelisted: `pypi.org` and `files.pythonhosted.org`
The problem is that pip is running on an older version. In my case pip was running on version  `9.0.1`. This version of pip tries to look for packages at an old url `pypi.python.org` which now is actually redirected to `pypi.org`

```
1 location(s) to search for versions of pip:
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/" in the cache
No cache entry available
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/pip/'): Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',))': /simple/pip/
```

You can upgrade pip offline by transferring the whl file. You can download it from here `https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5a/4a/39400ff9b36e719bdf8f31c99fe1fa7842a42fa77432e584f707a5080063/pip-20.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

### Upgrade pip by running:

`$ python3 -m pip install pip-20.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

### Verify pip is upgraded by running:

```
$ python3 -m pip show pip
Name: pip
Version: 20.2.2
Summary: The PyPA recommended tool for installing Python packages.
Home-page: https://pip.pypa.io/
Author: The pip developers
Author-email: distutils-sig@python.org
License: MIT
Location: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

The newer pip looks for packages at `pypi.org` directly and downloads all files required from `files.pythonhosted.org`.
Once pip was upgraded, I was able to install pip packages.

#### Important note :

Please ensure you have whitelisted `pypi.org` and `files.pythonhosted.org`. Without access to these domains pip wont be able to install any package using internet.